# Is there an F# cast function with type inference like Seq.cast?

Tags: casting, f#, type-inference

So I have some COM-types with hard-to-remember, long, unwieldy names, so I'd rather not have to type them out when casting from object if I can avoid it. With `Seq.cast` it'll infer the required type and cast as necessary.

Here's a simplified version with int instead:

```
> let o = 1 :> obj;;
val o : obj = 1

> let inc x = x+1;;
val inc : int -> int

> inc o;;

  inc o;;
  ----^

stdin(15,5): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    obj
```

Okay, makes sense. So we cast it:

```
> inc (o :?> int);;
val it : int = 2
```

However, if I cast it with Seq.cast I wouldn't need to explicitly write the type:

```
> inc ([o] |> Seq.cast |> Seq.head);;
val it : int = 2
```

Is there a function that works like `cast` below?

```
> inc (o |> cast);;
val it : int = 2
```

Is there an F# `cast` function with type inference like Seq.cast?

Comment: You perhaps expect way too much of `Seq.cast`: something as simple as `inc ([2.0] |> Seq.cast |> Seq.head)` will throw `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the 'unbox' and 'box' operators to take advantage of type inference

```
inc (unbox o)
```

Comment: Wow, that really did work, even with conversion between COM-interfaces!

Comment: Obviously, it will only work when the compiler can infer the type, and it might not infer the type you want. If you're happy with the answer please accept it so that the question is marked as answered.

Comment: @LeafGarland: this has nothing to do with type inference! Simply `unbox(box a)` preserves original type of `a`. So `inc unbox(box 2.0)` will throw a **runtime** exception.

Comment: @GeneBelitski, I don't understand your point. `unbox` requires the type to cast too e.g. `unbox<int> o` but if the type can be inferred then you can use `unbox o`, which seemed to be what the original question was about. Whether or not the cast/unbox is correct at runtime is a different matter surely?

Comment: @LeafGarland: You are absolutely right, I must take my comment back; both `box` and `unbox` are inlined generic functions from F# compiler's standpoint.

Answer (score 4):

As Leaf mentioned, `box` and `unbox` work for conversions to/from `obj`. For other types you can use the `upcast` or static cast operators (`:>`) for upcasting and the `downcast` or dynamic cast (`:?>`) operators for downcasting. A wildcard can be used in place of an explicit  type, for example: `x :?> _`.